# iOS - Writing NSDictionary to Localizable.strings

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

This question is continuum to that one: [iOS - Could I change the localizable.strings content during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625008/ios-could-i-change-the-localizable-strings-content-during-runtime)

The answer was useful, however, there is a problem that I am facing. The printed string doesn't include quotations (like these "") for single word keys and/or values. This made the Localizable.string invalid file. Hence, nothing is retrieved from it even for keys/values with correct format.

Example:

GBP = GBP;
Glossary = Glossary;
"Go_Location" = "Go to location";

First two are causing the file to be invalid strings file. How to fix that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved it by enumerating the dictionary and printing each key/value pair to an NSString, then to the strings file.

Here is the code:

```
__block NSString *languageAndGlossaryDictionary = @"";
[[self getGlossaryDictionary] enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    languageAndGlossaryDictionary = [languageAndGlossaryDictionary stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n\"%@\" = \"%@\";", key, obj];
}];
```

Comment: a) this will break as soon as any key or value contains a " or a newline

Comment: b) don't allocate 100s of strings. Use a NSMutableString

Comment: For a) no, it didn't and it worked like a charm. b) This is a performance issue. Thanks for the advice any way! c) why the -1?!

Comment: a) it does -- c) because of a and b

Comment: regarding a) what if the obj is 'the dog is called (NEWLINE) "nanny"'

Answer (score 5):

Use NSDictionary's

```
- (NSString *)descriptionInStringsFileFormat;
```

Then write the resulting string to a file using the appropriate encoding:

```
NSString* strings = [dict descriptionInStringsFileFormat];
[strings writeToFile: @"Localizable.strings" atomically: YES  encoding: NSUTF16StringEncoding  error: nil];
```

(Obviously add whatever error checking you need).

Comment: How do I get an individual string from the file?

Comment: @tentmaking : Convert the string to a dic by using NSDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: "STRINGS_PATH") and use it as key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)writeLocalizableFileFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary toURL:(NSURL *)url atomically:(BOOL)atomically
{
    NSMutableString *fileContent = [NSMutableString new];

    [dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        [fileContent appendFormat:@"\"%@\" = \"%@\";\n", [self escapeString:key], [self escapeString:obj]];
    }];

    return [fileContent writeToURL:url atomically:atomically encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}

- (NSString *)escapeString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *escapedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"];
    escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@"\\r"];
    escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
    return [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
}
```